# How do you use underscore's chain method to return the first item in a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, chaining, chain

Say I have an array of arrays, and I want to return the first element of each array within the array:

```
array = [[["028A","028B","028C","028D","028E"],
          ["028F","0290","0291","0292","0293"],
          ["0294","0295","0296","0297","0298"],
          ["0299","029A","029B","029C","029D"],
          ["029E","029F","02A0","02A1","02A2"]],
         [["02A3","02A4"],
          ["02A5", "02A6"]];
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
var firsts = [];
_.each(array, function(item){
  _.each(item, function(thisitem){
    firsts.push(_.first(thisitem));
  });
});
```

but what if I want to do it with underscore's `_.chain()` method? Just learning underscore, and so far seems very useful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could do it with [`flatten`](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) and [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) thusly:

```
var firsts = _.chain(array)
              .flatten(true) // This true is important.
              .map(function(a) { return a[0] })
              .value();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cm3CJ/

You use `flatten(true)` to convert your array-of-arrays-of-arrays into an array-of-arrays and then the `map` peels off the first element of each inner array.

If you want something shorter than the `map`, you could use [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) to pull out the first element of the inner arrays:

```
var firsts = _.chain(array)
              .flatten(true) // This true is important.
              .pluck(0)
              .value();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pM9Hq/

[`_.pluck`](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.5.2/underscore.js#L233) is just a `map` call anyway:

```
// Convenience version of a common use case of `map`: fetching a property.
_.pluck = function(obj, key) {
  return _.map(obj, function(value){ return value[key]; });
};
```

This one looks a lot more like the `.map(&:first)` that you'd use in Ruby so it might be more familiar to some people and more concise once you're used to `pluck`. If you really want something Rubyish, you could use a non-anonymous function with `map`:

```
var first  = function(a) { return a[0] };
var firsts = _.chain(array)
              .flatten(true) // This true is important.
              .map(first)
              .value();
```

Comment: I found the use of **pluck** very interesting in this context. It paves the way for extracting _seconds_, _thirds_, and so on.  

The Rubish solution, using **underscore** since the very beginning, could use as first line the following code: `var first = function(a) { return _.first(a); };`

Comment: @ChaosManor: You wouldn't even need `first` in your Underscore has `_.first`, you could just say `.map(_.first)`.